# extracting Middle name using R

Tags: r

I am new to R language I am facing problem to extract the middle name of a name like

Carlsson, Mr. Frans Olof
Heininen, Miss. Wendla Maria
Hays, Mrs. Charles Melville

here I want to select only the salutation for the name like Mr or Miss etc used in the middle of the name. Guide me that how can I do it.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
 gsub(".*, +([^ ]+).*", "\\1", str1)
 #[1] "Mr."   "Miss." "Mrs."
```

Or using `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(str1, perl("(?<=, )[^ ]+(?= +)"))
 #[1] "Mr."   "Miss." "Mrs."
```

Or `stri_extract` from `stringi`

```
 stri_extract(str1, regex="(?<=, )[^ ]+(?= +)")
 #[1] "Mr."   "Miss." "Mrs."
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- c('Carlsson, Mr. Frans Olof','Heininen, Miss. Wendla Maria',
           'Hays, Mrs. Charles Melville')
```

Answer (score 1):

If the names are all arranged with the middle name being in the last positions then this should do it:

```
 sapply( strsplit(str1, " "), tail, 1)
```

If the goal is to identify the honorifics, then I think a list oriented approach would be better, where you enumerate the acceptable designations: "Mr","Mr.","Mrs", "Mrs", Dr", "Dr.", "Doctor", "Prof". You can then tie them together with a paste( with "|" as the separator and use regexpr and regmatches to extract.

This is a somewhat less robust approach to the honorific question:

```
> str1 <- c('Carlsson, Mr. Frans Olof','Heininen, Miss. Wendla Maria',
            'Hays, Mrs. Charles Melville',"Feynmann, Prof. Richard", 
             "Livingstone, Dr. David")
> gsub("^(.+, )([Mrsi.PofD]+)( .+)", "\\2", str1)
[1] "Mr."   "Miss." "Mrs."  "Prof." "Dr."
```

Comment: Also if it's always the second position then `vapply(strsplit(x, " "), \`[\`, "", 2)`

Comment: But if its not always there, then you get the first name.

Comment: True.  It would be wonderful if OP improved the question :) There have been many questions with exciting titles and disappointing bodies lately.

Comment: Heh, that's the Internet for you I guess.